# Hibernate and Spring Connection Pool Defaults

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am working on an application which is based on Hibernate 5.1.9.Final and Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE

What I am trying to discover is what the default values for connecting to the relational database are, such as connection_timeout, maxConnections, etc.

I am trying to understand this existing project, and I don't have any of this configuration on that, but still, I see several connections on the Database -> Postgres.

How to discover what the defaults are? Are there defaults values? And what is the default connection pool framework? C3p0?

Answer (score 2):

The default connection pooling mechanisms in hibernate are not production, not even performance testing ready. Here is a quotation from hibernate documentation

> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite
>   rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is not
>   intended for use in a production system, or even for performance
>   testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and
>   stability. Just replace the hibernate.connection.pool_size property
>   with connection pool specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's
>   internal pool. For example, you might like to use c3p0.

The property setting up the number of pooled connections is:

hibernate.connection.pool_size

Here is an example C3P0 configuration:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver
hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydatabase
hibernate.connection.username = myuser
hibernate.connection.password = secret
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

recently Hikari is very popular choice for connection pooling.
https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/

Here is an example set of Hikari properties:

```
<property name="hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
  <property name="hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
  <property name="hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
  <property name="hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>
  <property name="hikari.maximumPoolSize">30</property>
  <property name="hikari.idleTimeout">30000</property>

  <!-- Database connection properties -->
  <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property>
  <property name="hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sample</property>
  <property name="hikari.dataSource.user">root</property>
  <property name="hikari.dataSource.password">tiger</property>
```

source:
https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2016/01/hibernate-hikaricp-example.html

Comment: Thanks Alexandar! Would you know what the default pool is?